# How to find the first non-zero number from the bottom up by referenced vehicle#?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I go from the bottom up (latest date starting on the bottom for each vehicle#), where I want to catch the first non-zero number after several zeros in a column, by vehicle number?

```
Veh #  Mvmt  City
1234    3    BNA
1234    0    JDS
1234    0    HGF
2578    6    PLO
2578    0    UYF
7765    4    IJH
7765    5    FRE
7765    0    WSC
7765    0    YTS
```

So, based on the above example, I would want the formula to find me BNA, PLO, and FRE, ignoring the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following formula:

**=IF(AND(B2>0,B3=0),C2,"")**

Column B is the Mvmt with the data in starting B2, write the formula in D2, the And will check if the number is followed by zero the response will be the corresponding value in column C and empty cell if it is followed by number and you can drag it down the column.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your list of vehicle numbers (and there are many examples on SO as to how to generate that, then you can use the formula:

```
F2: =LOOKUP(2,1/((Veh=E2)*(Mvmt<>0)),City)
```

and fill down. (Where `E2` contains the unique vehicle number)

[image]